# Ошибка TypeError: 'list' object is not callable python

Tags: python

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')


@bot.message_handlers(command=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'саламалейкум')
```

Comment: Где возникает ошибка?

Comment: вот здесь:@bot.message_handlers(command=['start'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня была похожая ошибка, когда я начинал.

Дело в том, что вы перепутали bot.message_handler с bot.message_handlerS.
А еще вы задали неверный аргумент для декоратора command, а надо commands.
Будьте внимательны)

Рабочий код:

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('<Ваш токен>')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text='Привет')

bot.polling()
```

Comment: спасибо большое